# the code doesn't speed up while using Intel Intrinsics

Tags: c++, opencv, sse, intrinsics

I am using intrinsics to accelerate the running openCV code. But after i replaced the code with Intrinsics, the runtime cost of the code is almost the same or maybe even worse. i cannot figure out what and why this is happening. I have been searching this issue for quite long time but noting change. It is appreciated if someone can help me out. Thank you very much! Here is my code

```
      // if useSSE is true,run the code with intrinsics and takes 1.45ms in my computer 
      // and if not run the general code and takes the same time.
     cv::Mat<float> results(shape.rows,2);
     if (useSSE) {
        float* pshape = (float*)shape.data;
        results = shape.clone();
        float* presults = (float*)results.data;
        // use SSE
        __m128 xyxy_center = _mm_set_ps(bbox.center_y, bbox.center_x, bbox.center_y, bbox.center_x);

        float bbox_width = bbox.width/2;
        float bbox_height = bbox.height/2;
        __m128 xyxy_size = _mm_set_ps(bbox_height, bbox_width, bbox_height, bbox_width);
        gettimeofday(&start, NULL); // this is for counting time

        int shape_size = shape.rows*shape.cols;
        for (int i=0; i<shape_size; i +=4) {
            __m128 a = _mm_loadu_ps(pshape+i);
            __m128 result = _mm_div_ps(_mm_sub_ps(a, xyxy_center),  xyxy_size);
            _mm_storeu_ps(presults+i, result);
        }
    }else {
        //SSE TO BE DONE
        for (int i = 0; i < shape.rows; i++){
            results(i, 0) = (shape(i, 0) - bbox.center_x) / (bbox.width / 2.0);
            results(i, 1) = (shape(i, 1) - bbox.center_y) / (bbox.height / 2.0);
        }
    }
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    diff = 1000000*(end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec)+end.tv_sec-start.tv_usec;
    std::cout<<diff<<"-----"<<std::endl;
    return results;
```

Comment: A _working_ code may help you to get some answer. Please see how to do a [mcve]

Comment: Also, you should describe what your code do.

Comment: Do you really need the `div_ps` there or is it ok to multiply by the reciprocal?

Comment: Which compiler? For example, if you're using Windows and VS2012 or above, you'll probably find that these simple `for` loops are [automatically vectorized](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh872235%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Call to gettimeofday probably dwarfs everything else. You should consider hoisting the timing out of the function body and timing 1000000 calls to it instead. Also, you don't appear to be aligning your values.

Comment: Is there make much differences if I use Mac OS and Xcode to compile the code because I have call the cvCheckHardwareSupport(CV_CPU_SSE) method to check if it is supported the SSE?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your SSE optimization will corrupt memory near results variable, if shape.rows % 2 == 1
2. Try avoiding using i variable in the loop, use pointers directly. Compiler may optimize additional plus operation, or it may not.
3. Use multiplication instead of division:

   ```
   float bbox_width_inv = 2./bbox.width;
   float bbox_height_inv = 2./bbox.height;
   __m128 xyxy_size = _mm_set_ps(bbox_height, bbox_width, bbox_height, bbox_width);
   float* p_shape_end = p_shape + shape.rows*shape.cols;
   float* p_shape_end_batch = p_shape + shape.rows*shape.cols & (~3);
   for (; p_shape<p_shape_end_batch; p_shape+=4, presults+=4) {
       __m128 a = _mm_loadu_ps(pshape);
       __m128 result = _mm_mul_ps(_mm_sub_ps(a, xyxy_center),  xyxy_size_inv);
       _mm_storeu_ps(presults, result);
   }
   while (p_shape < p_shape_end) {
       presults++ = (p_shape++ - bbox.center_x) * bbox_width_inv;
       presults++ = (p_shape++ - bbox.center_y) * bbox_height_inv;
   }
   ```
4. Try to disassemble code generated from intrinsics, and make sure there is enough registers to perform your operations, and it doesn't store temporary results into RAM

Comment: Thank you for all the advices you gave me! For the first, the shape.rows is 2 by default and sorry for i didn't make it clear. For the others, I have tried these improvement, but it doesn't make any difference for the result of running time.

Comment: changing division to multiplication didn't helped?

Comment: Nop...yeah, that's very strange